# Error in the installation of PCRE

Tags: makefile, pcre

I downloaded the latest release of the PCRE library from http://www.pcre.org, obtaining a tar.gz file.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1.

Then I use

> gzip -d pcre-*NN*.tar.gz 
>   tar xvf pcre-*NN*.tar 
>   cd pcre-*NN* 
>   ./configure 
>   make

and then I obtain this error

> libtool: compile: unrecognized option `-DHAVE_CONFIG_H' 
>  
>   libtool: compile: Try `libtool --help' for more information. 
>   make[1]: *** [pcrecpp.lo] Error 1

Then i find out that *libtool* was not installed, and so

> sudo apt-get install libtool

But even now, the *make* has the same error ...

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing. It installs all libraries needed to build pcre

```
apt-get build-dep libpcre3-dev
```

Comment: Thank you! But when I try to install the Apache Server, it says that it doesn't find the pcre-config for libpcre ...

Comment: so why do you want to install the newest pcre anyway? Isn't the one from Ubuntu good enough?

Comment: Unfortunately during the Apache's _configure_, it says that libpcre is not found.

Comment: Make sure you do `apt-get install build-essential` first just in case.

Comment: Ok. With build-essential I resolve the problem. But what does the package contain?

Comment: All the compilers and tools you need to build packages manually on Ubuntu